# How to prove that the intersection of all inductive sets is equal to the intersection of all inductive subsets of an arbitrary inductive set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A set $y$ is defined as inductive if and only if $\emptyset \in y$ and $x^{+} \in y$ for all $x \in y$, where $x^{+} = x \cup \left\{x\right\}$. The set of all natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is then defined as the intersection of all inductive sets. It is also pointed out that $\mathbb{N}$ can be defined as the intersection of all inductive subsets of an arbitrary inductive set (the existence of one inductive set is assumed). I am wondering how to prove that these two definitions are equivalent.

P.S. I have no problem admitting that "the intersection of all inductive subsets of an arbitrary inductive set" is a subset of "the intersection of all inductive sets". However, how should I prove the inverse direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some inductive set $I$.

One direction is immediate: intersections of *bigger* families are *smaller* (if $A\subseteq B$ then $\bigcap B\subseteq\bigcap A$), so the intersection of all inductive sets is a subset of the intersection of all inductive subsets of $I$.

*This is the opposite of the direction you've said is already understood, but I suspect that was a typo.*

For the converse inclusion, suppose $a$ is *not* in every inductive set; we want to find an inductive subset of $I$ not containing $a$. So suppose $J$ is an inductive set with $a\not\in J$. There's a useful lemma which lets us build new inductive sets from old ones: **if $X,Y$ are inductive, then so is $X\cap Y$**. This means that $I\cap J$ is an inductive set. Now, is $a\in I\cap J$?

Answer (score 1):

It’s actually the other inclusion that is automatic.

Let $S$ be an inductive set, let $\mathscr{S}$ be the set of all inductive subsets of $S$, and let $\mathscr{I}$ be the class of all inductive sets. Then $\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{I}$, so $\bigcap\mathscr{I}\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr{S}$: when you intersect more sets, you get a smaller intersection.

To show that $\bigcap\mathscr{S}\subseteq\bigcap\mathscr{I}$, we prove the contrapositive. Suppose that $x\notin\bigcap\mathscr{I}$. Then there is an inductive set $J$ such that $x\notin J$. $S\cap J$ is inductive (why?), so $x\notin S\cap J\in\mathscr{S}$, and therefore $x\notin\bigcap\mathscr{S}$.

Comment: I guess the key point is to know that the intersection of inductive sets is inductive.

Comment: @ZiqiFan: Yes, that really is the key.